# Access Flask instance when using Flask-Script

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

I am creating a flask instance using:

application/**init**.py:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    mongo = PyMongo(app)
    ...
    return app
```

manage.py

```
app = create_app(Config.FLASK_CONFIG)
manager = Manager(app)
```

with application started using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

In views I would like to access the mongo instance created in app. Any idea how I can access the PyMongo wrapper around app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__.py`, initialize app and mongo to `None`.

```
app = None
mongo = None
```

Create a separate `setup.py` module in `application` and move create_app factory function there. The reason for this approach is so as to bind Flask application instance and mongo instance to your application package.

Also, refactor the app factory separating the database factory from it since we need to keep the database instance around.

```
import application

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ....
    return app

def create_mongo(app):
    return PyMongo(app)

app = create_app(Config.FLASK_CONFIG)

# bind to application package
application.app = app
application.mongo = create_mongo(app)
```

In `manage.py`, rewrite this to use the app instance created in `setup.py` module.

```
from application.setup import app

manager = Manager(app)
```

Mongo instance can be imported directly from the application package because the instance was bound earlier to the package in setup.

```
from application import mongo
```

#### NOTE:

You may care to know that initializing a PyMongo instance registers `pymongo` as an extension in your flask application.

The connection and database are bound to a `config_prefix` key whose default value is `'MONGO'` in the registered extension. They can both be retrieved like so:

```
cx, db = app.extensions['pymongo']['MONGO']
```

#### Reference

- [Registering PyMongo extension in Flask application](https://github.com/dcrosta/flask-pymongo/blob/0.5.0/flask_pymongo/__init__.py#L284)

Comment: May be a dumb question, but how can I get app, it exists inside the create_app function called by the flask_script manager.

Comment: You should return the Flask `app` instance in `create_app` factory function. I advise that you also return the mongo instance instead of accessing from extensions

Comment: as per manage.py code above in my question app is returned, and exists in the manage.py module - how to get access from outside this module?

Comment: It doesnt seem right that I import app from manage.py wherever I need database access - as this leads to circular arguments as manager is calling modules on setup.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I can see circular import errors will be an issue the way the application is set up currently.